# Cellular Automata in Java 3D

Tags: java, 3d, java-3d, cellular-automata

I have created a Cellular Automata implementation in Java 3D. Everything is working correctly but I would need some starting patterns to start off with. As of now I have 2 cell states: Visible and Invisible. 
Now my question is: how would I define a cylindrical pattern, for example, of Visible cells to initiate the simulation with? I have searched the web but I'm not getting any results, it seems. Is there some sort of formula to define the bounds with for a cylindrical one?

Any advice or pointing me in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)? I imagine you have, but just in case it's a cellular automata turn-based "game." There are a few good "starting positions" [on the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Examples_of_patterns).